# Building confidence interval with t-distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, t-distribution

I am wondering wether i have to use normal or t distribution in the following situation

I have a population of 1000 individuals. I'm interested in $P$ the sum of all $x_i$ where $x_i$ is the value of the variable of interest of the $i^{th}$ individual.  i'm estimating $P$ with $\hat{P} = 1000 * \bar{x}_n $

I'm taking a sample of 3 individuals (without replacement) and i want to generate a 95% confidence interval for $\hat{P}$.

> it going to look like this
>
> > $1000*\bar{x}_3 ± (some\_statistics) * \sqrt{s^2}$

I initially assumed normal Z value (for 0.025 and 0.975) but i remembered something about t distribution and small sample count with unknown variance. Should i switch my Z stats to a T statistics (with $\nu = 2$)

Thank you very much

Comment: Unless you are careful about the meaning of "$s^2$", or include more than a quantile of $t_2$ in "some statistics," this formula could be terribly wrong.  Could you provide the specific formula you have in mind?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. By $\sqrt{s^2}$  i meant "standard deviation". I wanted to exclude it from the discussion ( but i plan to use "standard deviation" = $\sqrt{\frac{s^2}{n}(1-\frac{n}{N})} $). Some statistic is either $Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ or $T_{\frac{\alpha}{2};\nu=2}$